# ubuntu 10.04 DHCP server upgraded and now severe problems

Tags: 10.04, graphics, filesystem, dhcp

We have an Ubuntu server at work. It acts as a DHCP server for 5 machines connected to a private 172.x.x.x network for internet access. The machines netboot from an image on the server.

I tried to update the list of MAC addresses to add some new machines to the system, following instructions from our ex support company. It couldn't find the .txt file even though it was in the same folder. I Googled and it suggested file corruption.

There were about 60 updates pending. I originally selected no but after trying to reboot into recovery mode mode I think I must have said yes to these updates by accident.

After installing the updates and rebooting, there are multiple graphics issues:

- No window decorations
- Menus don't work.
- Firefox doesn't really work
- Sometimes X just doesn't work at all. I'm left with TTYs.

I've never used unix/ubuntu before. And the support company has gone bust! I'm assuming that there was some file corruption already, but the huge update has also changed some of the settings for the DHCP and the video, along with who knows what else.

How to solve these issues ?

Comment: You main blocker certainly appears to be a simple graphics driver issue but you haven't indicated what you're running. Could you edit your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1` please?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration sounds like it's been set up manually. The default DHCP settings will auto-allocate IP addresses to new MAC addresses ad store that lease for a period of time.

The settings, by they way, aren't in a `.txt` file. They're at `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` and you can edit them from the console with nano like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf
```

You should be able to edit that without the graphical session. I don't know why there's even a desktop installed. Most Ubuntu servers work headlessly (without a monitor or desktop). It's certainly unneccessary for a DHCP server.

Nothing you've described suggests corruption. It all points to you not having a clue what you're doing yet you're still making systemic changes. I don't understand how you could think this would end in anything but pain... Now you're in a position where a server and all its clients are down. And you're also getting close to the end of the lifespan of 10.04. The desktop support (ie Firefox and all the other graphical applications) have already expired. You shouldn't be using them. You need to upgrade the entire OS.

In short, everything's broken and you don't know how to fix any of it... It sounds to me like you desperately need to engage the services of a new support company. Or employ somebody with Ubuntu server experience (not that hard these days).